# Forcing download of excel file through Ajax request fails silently

Tags: php, excel, file, http-headers

I am trying to make a link that is clickable; when it's clicked on it forces a download (or even a Save As option would be nice) of an `.xls` file.  This is what I have below.

When the link is clicked, there are no php log errors and it goes through this code.  The file does exist as well.  Are my headers wrong?

```
if (@file_exists("/tmp/report/{$php_session_id}.xls")) {
    $filename = "/tmp/report/{$php_session_id}.xls";
    $content_length = filesize($filename);

    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-length: {$content_length}");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"missing_addresses.xml\"");

    readfile($filename);


}
```

If the code is correct, is it possibly a server that is locked out of doing this?

Also, I am testing on Chrome for Mac (newest version)

UPDATE:  I used AJAX which was the problem.

Comment: What do you mean "it goes through this code"? What exactly happens?

Comment: I mean there are no errors that are stopping it from executing.  I did an `echo` statement at the end and it "goes thru" to that `echo`.

Comment: Well, is the `file_exists()` condition ever fulfilled?

Comment: So what is sent to the client? Either check using a network sniffer or put an output buffer around the code and check its content.

Comment: @Pekka웃 yes the file does exist so the condition is fulfilled.

Comment: You do not say what is actually happening when you click the link. Does the page stay what it is or is something else shown?

Comment: And why do you write of an excel file whilst you are sending an xml header and specifying an text/xml mime type? Those two Content-type headers definitely do not make sense.

Comment: @arkascha  sorry, typo.  I have removed it (still doesn't work)

Comment: "still doesn't work"... (sight) What DOES happen then?

Comment: @arkascha  When you click the link, I (1) create a file, (2) then push it for download.  happens thru AJAX.  The link operates on a JavaScript onClick function.  So a file is created behind the scenes but nothing happens visible to user (as in, no donwload forced).

Comment: AJAX? What? Don't you think that might have been a valuable information from the beginning? And where is that ajax code?

Comment: You can't initiate a download through Ajax, it'll simply vanish in the ether. Use `location.href = "source.php";` instead.

Comment: @Pekka웃  Thanks, this is first time I use AJAX to try this.  I had no idea on that.  Let me try to change things up then.

Comment: @KickingLettuce yeah. Alternatively, `<a href='source.php' target='_blank'>` should have the same effect without using any JavaScript at all

Comment: @Pekka웃  Thanks you can put this as answer as to why it's not working.  I will do the rest.  Not looking for any code answers just a "why".

Comment: Always a good idea to call exit(0)  after sending a file, to prevent anything else working its way onto the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't initiate a download through Ajax; the response will simply vanish in the ether, as a normal Ajax response. (You could theoretically capture it, but you won't be able to write it to disk.)

Use

> location.href = "source.php";

or

```
<a href='source.php' target='_blank'>
```

to direct the browser to the resource directly instead. It will automatically detect that it's a file to be downloaded, and initiate the download.